# Spinor-helicity variables and gauge transformations of the polarization vector

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization, helicity

I am reading Clifford Cheung's [2017 TASI Lectures on Scattering Amplitudes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.03872). In section 2, "Crash Course in Kinematics", the spinor-helicity variables are introduced and discussed. In terms of these variables, the polarization vectors are defined as,
\begin{align}
e^+_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} = \frac{\eta \widetilde{\lambda}}{\langle \eta \lambda\rangle}, \quad e^-_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} = \frac{\lambda \widetilde{\eta}}{[\widetilde{\lambda}\widetilde{\eta}]}, \tag{2.13}
\end{align}
where $\eta$ and $\widetilde{\eta}$ are reference spinors, solely required to be linear independent from the spinors $\lambda$ and $\widetilde{\lambda}$. Then, we consider a redefinition of these reference spinors, and the induced transformation of the polarization vectors,

\begin{align}
\eta \rightarrow \eta' = a\eta + b \lambda. \tag{2.15}
\end{align}
given the linear independence, this linear combination is always possible for some $a$ and $b$. Then we have,

\begin{align}
e^+_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} \rightarrow (e^+_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}})' = (a\eta + b \lambda)\frac{\widetilde{\lambda}}{\langle \eta \lambda \rangle} = a e^+_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} + b (\lambda \widetilde{\lambda}) \frac{1}{\langle \eta \lambda \rangle} \stackrel{!}{=} e^+_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} + \left(\frac{b}{a \langle \eta \lambda\rangle}\right) p_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}.
\end{align}
Cheung summarizes this with,

> which is literally a gauge transformation. So the polarizations do change
> depending on the choice of reference but in a way that leaves the amplitude
> invariant by the Ward identity.

I have a few issues with this relation, which I've explicated beyond what appears in the text:

1. How is it that the expression is seemingly divided by $a$ in the final step? Wouldn't that define a different shift of the reference spinor $\eta$ in (2.15)?
2. It isn't obvious to me that this is a gauge transformation. I'm familiar with gauge transformations of fields, in QED $A_\mu(x) \rightarrow A_\mu(x) + \partial_\mu \lambda(x)$, but here the claim is that we have a transformation of the polarization vector? It's clear to me that the orthogonality is preserved between $e$ and $p$. I think this might just come down to my lack of familiarity with the Ward identity derivation.